# ValueError: could not convert string tofloat. why? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

> how to convert str in float?

```
paris=requests.get('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=paris').json()
paris_latlong=paris[0]['latt_long']
a=float(paris_latlong)
print(a)
```

> ValueError: could not convert string tofloat.

Comment: Can you tell us what ```paris_latlong``` is?

Comment: '48.856930,2.341200'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
paris=requests.get('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=paris').json()
paris_latlong=paris[0]['latt_long'].split(',')
a=float(paris_latlong[0])
b=float(paris_latlong[1])
print(a, b)
```